Security of AES-128 encryption compared to wrapping
AES-128 encrypting the key versus AES Key Wrap. Which one would be the more secure mode of operation to protect encryption keys in storage?
Specifically, will both method have same security level against brute-force attack or quantum attack using Grover’s algorithm? AES Key Wrap uses 64bit blocks; will that property make it more vulnerable to such attack?

Background knowledge on blockcipher mode of operation will answer this question. Give it a look on Wikipedia (or whatever reference available to you).

This question is similar to: Which is the best AES mode of operation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Good edit, I guess that makes it a bit different of a question that the one mentioned. I don't expect a huge difference when talking about the block size, but that's just an educated guess.

Can we remove the "brute force" part? That's just going over all wrapping keys, and both algorithms have the same key size. If it isn't directly possible to verify that the wrapped key is correct then it is still possible to verify correctness by applying the found key for its specific use case. That requires an oracle of some kind, but that's usually implied.
